How do I scan both pages on a piece of paper using Document Scanner 42.0?
I am trying to do 2-sided copy using the Document Scanner app via the top feeder of a Canon E4570 scanner-printer.
The picture below shows the app setting before clicking Scan. The app is able to scan the top page of the paper but not the bottom page of the paper. How do I activate duplex scanning?
System and App Info:

system: Linux 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu
canon firmware: 1.070
document scanner: 42.0




Can you post a screenshot of the preferences window?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Scan Sides is set at Both but it did not work.

Can you try skanpage instead? Install it with the command sudo apt install skanpage qml-module-org-kde-kquickimageeditor (the kquickimageeditor is a required dependency that does not get automatically installed). Then, enable ADF Duplex in the settings

If this is the version of Ubuntu 22.04.3 you are behind in updates. Start there first. sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

@DavidDE I have ran those commands and even restarted the computer. Still having the same issue and the system is still Linux 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC

@ArchismanPanigrahi No apt package "skanpage", but there is a snap with that name. Try "snap install skanpage"

I see. Perhaps skanpage was added to 24.04 and is absent in 22.04. Can you try the snap? sudo snap install skanpage

Whilst some printers are capable of double sided printing, the document feeder is often not capable of reloading the pages once they have passed through the feeder (except in some very expensive devices).
If your device falls into this category (my HP Colour LaserJet MFP-278-281 falls in to this category) you may find this document I created of some use as a guide to scanning single sides in Document Scanner (Simple Scan as it was then) and then re-ordering the pages in the application so that your document is printed correctly as a two sided document with the pages correctly in order.
I know the arrangement works, I've done it many times and always come back to this reference when required.

Double sided scanning with single sided document feeders
Place your documents in the feeder, side A up. Click "Scan All Pages
From Feeder" to scan them all. When complete, remove the documents
from the tray, flip the pages over so that the last page is on top and
place back in the feeder top inwards as before. Go back to Simple Scan
and click "Scan All Pages From Feeder" again, and side B of the sheets
will be scanned. Great, however side B are in the reverse order, and
all after side A...
Not to worry, Simple Scan has a fix - go to the menu (top right
corner), select "Reorder Pages".
The pop-up box gives a few options, but the one we want for this is
"Combine pages (reverse)" (top right) - one click and the document is
re-ordered correctly! Save as a PDF or series of images.


